# Determining search results quality in Lucene

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval

I have been searching about score normalization for few days (**now i know this can't be done**) in Lucene using mailing list, wiki, blogposts, etc. I'm going to expose my problem because I'm not sure that score normalization is what our project need.

**Background**:
  In our project, we are using Solr on top of Lucene with custom RequestHandlers and SearchComponents. For a given query, we need to detect when a query got poor results to trigger different actions.

**Assumptions**: 
  Inmutable index (once indexed, it is not updated) and Same query tipology (dismax qparser with same field boosting, without boost functions nor boost queries).

**Problem**:
  We know that score normalization is not implementable. But is there any way to determine (using TF/IDF and boost field assumptions) when search results match quality are poor?

Example: We've got an index with science papers and other one with medcare centre's info. When a user query against first index and got poor results (inferring it from score?), we want to query second index and merge results using some threshold (score threshold?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're right that normalization of scores across different queries doesn't make sense, because  nearly all similarity measures base on term frequency, which is of course local to a query.

However, I think that it is viable to compare the scores in this very special case that you are describing, if only you would override the default similarity to use IDF calculated jointly for both indexes. For instance, you could achieve it easily by keeping all the documents in one index and adding an extra (and hidden to the users) 'type' field. Then, you could compare the absolute values returned by these queries.

Generally, it could be possible to determine low quality results by looking at some features, like for example very small number of results, or some odd distributions of scores, but I don't think it actually solves your problem. It looks more similar to the issue of merging of isolated search results, which is discussed for example in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.21.3080&rep=rep1&type=pdf).